# How to show UI in GLSurfaceView based game Android?

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I am building a game which contains a `GLSurfaceView`. This `GLSurfaceView` receives all touch events and based on that game proceeds. Now based on certain conditions i want to show certain dialog box. Say game ends on a double tap, I want to show a dialog box saying if user wants to restart. But i guess these events are not handled in UI thread so when I am trying to create dialog box my app is crashing. How can I achieve this ?

Code which is creating this dialog:

```
 Context ctx = MainActivity.getContext();
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            builder.setTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.ThemeSelectionDialogTitle));
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            final CharSequence[] items={"Theme 1", "Theme 2"};

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    if("Theme 1".equals(items[which]))
                    {
                        Log.i(LOGUtil.LOG_TAG, "Theme 1 Selected");
                    }
                    else if("Theme 2".equals(items[which]))
                    {
                        Log.i(LOGUtil.LOG_TAG, "Theme 2 Selected");
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

CallStack:

> DalvikVM[localhost:8600]      Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception
>   WindowManager$BadTokenException))         
>         ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) line:
>   5662          ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents() line: 5588
>         ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(InputEvent, InputEventReceiver, int,
>   boolean) line: 5559
>         ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(InputEvent) line:
>   5737
>         ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver(InputEventReceiver).dispatchInputEvent(int,
>   InputEvent) line: 185         MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(int, int) line:
>   not available [native method]         MessageQueue.next() line: 138
>         Looper.loop() line: 123         ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5086
>         Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native method]          Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 515          ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line:
>   785           ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 601 
>         NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
>     Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
>     Thread [<11> GLThread 4824] (Running)       Thread [<12> Binder_3]
>   (Running)

Relevant Logcat Output:

> D/SomeSDK( 3817): Game Draw !!! D/WifiStateMachine( 1068):
>   handleMessage: E msg.what=151572 D/WifiStateMachine( 1068):
>   processMsg: ConnectedState D/WifiStateMachine( 1068): processMsg:
>   L2ConnectedState W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not
>   implement UiTask. Consider using NamedUiRunnable for
>   Consumers.consumeAsync W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not
>   implement UiTask. Consider using NamedUiRunnable for
>   Consumers.consumeAsync W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not
>   implement UiTask. Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@4210c078 ...
>   ...
>
> D/WifiStateMachine( 1068): handleMessage: X
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@4210c078 ... ...
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for Consumers.consumeAsync
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for Consumers.consumeAsync
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@42103ca8 ... ...
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for Consumers.consumeAsync
>   D/dalvikvm(27831): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2085K, 39% free 10594K/17184K,
>   paused 2ms+2ms, total 26ms D/dalvikvm(27831): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC
>   blocked 18ms D/dalvikvm(27831): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
>   D/dalvikvm(27831): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
>   D/dalvikvm(27831): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for Consumers.consumeAsync
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@420abc18
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@420a7a80... ...
>
> W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@4233f958
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for Consumers.consumeAsync ... ...
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@421b6100
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@420abc18
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@420a7a80
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@42099068
>   W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(27831): Task does not implement UiTask.
>   Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@42096ed8 W

Comment: Post your logcat with the entire stack backtrce. All user touch events are delivered on your ui thread, so something else is going on.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Added CallStack and Code snippet. Logcat is not giving any useful information

Comment: Can you add the code around where you are creating the dialog? Where did `ctx` come from?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer added code . `ctx` comes from a static variable in `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` contains `GLSurfaceView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Activity` instance as your context rather than a static context, like that application context. The dialog is bound to the lifecycle of your `Activity` so it needs the instance rather than a static which may no longer be valid.

Comment: ok ! I dont get this completely. Right now i am using application context which is stored in that static variable. You are saying that might not even be valid. `MainActivity` contains `GLSurfaceView` and that contains a `GameController` which needs to show this alert. So I need to pass that Activity Instance all the way to this class ?

Comment: Yes. Your `Activity` is an instance of `Context` and is tied to a `Window`. Any dialog you create will be tied to the `Activity`, which is transient. Your application context is a singleton for your app process and has no window associated with it.